# swift Lost data from the realm database in another country

Tags: swift, realm

I use the `realm` database for my application (to-do list), everything works fine, BUT once I flew to another country and noticed that the records in the database are empty (the application gives out an empty list), upon arrival back to my country everything returned to normal ... Now I am again in a different country and the situation repeats again (database is empty), for some reason the database gives an empty list result, can you please explain why this is happening and how to fix that?

Output example

```
var dbToDoList = DBrealmToDoList()
var arrayToDoList: Results<RealmToDoList> {
    get {
        return dbToDoList.getArray()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    dbToDoList.realm = realm

    let current = arrayToDoList.filter { (_todo) -> Bool in
        return _todo.date == date
    }.first
    self.selectedDate = date
    if current != nil {
        self.selectedLists = current?.lists
        self.selectedListsSorted =     self.selectedLists?.sorted(by: { (val, val2) -> Bool in
            return (!val.value && val2.value)
            })
    }
}
```

And then in `tableView` I display the data from the `selectedListsSorted`

```
// MARK: UITableView
extension ToDoListViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  selectedListsSorted?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ToDoListTableViewCell
        let current = selectedListsSorted?[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = current?.key
        cell.checkBox.isSelected = current?.value ?? false
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90
    }
 
}
```

Here is a class for working with db

```
class RealmToDoList: Object {
    @objc private dynamic var dictionaryData: Data?
    var lists: [String: Bool] {
        get {
            guard let dictionaryData = dictionaryData else {
                return [String: Bool]()
            }
            do {
                let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dictionaryData, options: []) as? [String: Bool]
                return dict!
            } catch {
                return [String: Bool]()
            }
        }

        set {
            do {
                let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newValue, options: [])
                dictionaryData = data
            } catch {
                dictionaryData = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc dynamic var date : Date?
}

class DBrealmToDoList {
    var realm: Realm!
    
    func write(_ data: RealmToDoList) throws -> Bool {
        var result = false
        
        if (realm != nil) {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(data)
                result = true
            }
            return result
        } else {
            throw RuntimeError.NoRealmSet
        }
        
    }
    
    func getArray() -> Results<RealmToDoList> {
        return realm.objects(RealmToDoList.self)
    }
    
    func delete(_ data: RealmToDoList) throws -> Bool {
        var result = false
        if (realm != nil) {
            try! self.realm.write {
                self.realm.delete(data)
                result = true
            }
            return result
        } else {
            throw RuntimeError.NoRealmSet
        }
    }
    
    func update(ofType:Object,value:AnyObject,key:String)->Bool{
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            try  realm.write {
                ofType.setValue(value, forKeyPath: key)
            }
            
            return true
        }catch let error as NSError {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func filter(id:Int) -> RealmToDoList? {
        let match = realm.objects(RealmToDoList.self).filter("id == %@",id).first
        return match
    }
  
    func newToDoList(date : Date?,lists: [String: Bool]) -> RealmToDoList{
        let pill = RealmToDoList()
        pill.date = date
        pill.lists = lists
        return pill
    }
}
```

I doubt that the matter is in the database, but I cannot understand what it is, because I don’t do a filter by country, etc.

Comment: Thanks for translating. I have nominated your question for reopening, though it might still take a while for it to earn enough supporting votes.

Comment: This is a vague question and I am a bit surprised the code works as is. First, we don't know if this is a local or sync'd Realm; if it's local then all of the data is stored on the device and location is not relevant. Also, this `var realm: Realm!` is not how Realm is initialized so calling this `func getArray()` would always fail because Realm was not initialized before calling it. Reviewing the Getting Started Guide [Opening A Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start/#open-a-realm) may help. Also, I don't believe Realm supports AnyObject so `func update` won't work either.

Comment: @Jay yes, i did `let realm = try! Realm() dbToDoList.realm = realm` in the `viewDidLoad` method and its only local sync

Comment: I am confused too, why in different country database return empty value.

Comment: You don't have that in your code, except in `func update`. I made an err in my above comment about the `func update` - AnyObject will work in that case. However, the code in the question is still incomplete and Realm is not initialized correctly. Please review  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If we don't have accyrate code, we're not going to be able to help.

Comment: @Jay added code for u. I dont think this is something wrong with my code, cuz it's working fine

Comment: can u help please

Comment: It's probably the date because the date will change based on time zone and if you're selecting today's date/time in one time zone, it will be different that's what's in the database. e.g. if you create a new date/time it will be today in this timezone but could be yesterday in a different time zone.

Comment: @Jay yeah, u is right. Thank you! u can post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the date because the date will change based on time zone and if you're selecting today's date/time in one time zone, it will be different that's what's in the database. So if a filter is based on this date

```
@objc dynamic var date : Date?
```

then that date will be "today" for whatever time zone you're in but a "today" date that was created this morning in a different time zone will not return the current time zones date.

e.g. if you create a new date/time it will be today in this timezone but could be yesterday in a different time zone.